# Servlet application with RESTFul Urls

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I have a small legacy application which is created using the old servlet style approach wherein
it extends HTTPServlet.  The URLS are mapped with query parameters

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/servlet/ReportServlet?id=CA
```

Now they wanted it to be rewritten and follow REST Urls style.

```
http://localhost8080/MyApp/servlet/ReportServlet/id/CA
```

I dont know much how this is done so I'd like to ask for guidance on how to create a web application
with REST urls.
Most of the servlet tutorials uses annotations but never speaks about creating RESTFUL URL

I have searched SO but cant find similar questions so feel free to closed this if this is a duplicate but kindly
point me to a resource that teaches this.
Note that I am not looking into creating a RESTFul web service but how to create a Session Based Web Applications
using HTTPServlet.

I am not to keen on using any specific frameworks so just with the bare JEE stack.

Comment: Are you trying to keep your old servlet and just change the URL scheme? Or are you happy to re-factor your servlet into a JAX-RS REST approach?

Comment: Oh that's a good question.  I dont want to be greedy but can you give me pointers on how it is to be done in both ways.  I would like to evaluate then if keeping or refactoring should be done since I really dont know how this is done.  Thank you for asking this.

Comment: Simply changing the URL pattern would be quite easy, just change the mappings in your web.xml descriptor, and update the URLs in your views. On the other hand, migrating to a full REST architecture would require rewriting a good part of your View layer (controllers and views).

Comment: I think its okay to migrate to a full REST but I just cant find a good resource that tells me this.  Most uses SPRING MVC but I havent used this for sometime.